# How to make an animation aiming an specific character speed (for a game)?

Tags: animation

So, I need to make a run animation for my game. Considering motion capture isn't an option for now, I believe I have only 2 ways to build this, in place animation or moving the character's root around. Almost all tutorials regarding animation (for games) are made with in place loops, this tells me this way is the best or at least the easiest way to do things. But I would like to animate the character running at an specific speed, let's say 30 km/h. Because of that requirement, I think the animation must be built moving the character's root. That being said, is there any way to actually measure the root speed in Blender before hand?

This was my rational behind the doubt, feel free to point any misconceptions that I might have said.

Comment: Well, 30 km/h is about 8 m/s, and a full-size human's stride is about 1 meter, so your character needs to take about 8 or 9 strides per second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, a sprint stride should be more than that as the movement is more broad than a regular stride. I still have doubts about how to build the animation itselft, but I'll try to make more tests before asking more questions.

Comment: I searched for [pose running method](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pose+running+method&iax=images) and found some nice sequences you could use as reference images. Note that in the Pose method speed is increased by increasing cadence not stride length.

Comment: Thanks you, but I wasn't talk about the poses. My doubts now are related the way I should animate, I believe I must build in place animations to import in Unity, but doing that, I can't tell the what the actual speed of the character. Like I said, there are more things to consider here, I'll try to make some tests, my next question would probably belong to the gamedev session...

Comment: Just figure out that the animation must be build moving the root in my case, if I use stationary clips, I would need to add the root motion inside Unity using it's animation curve system, which seems a little harder to work with. So I think I must animate moving the character around in the end..